# What is the maximum value of $k$ so that $x^2+4(\sin^{2}{x}\tan^{2}{x}+\cos^{2}{x}\cot^{2}{x}+k^2-x\sec{x}\csc{x})=0$ has real roots.

Tags: trigonometry, polynomials

> What is the largest value of $k$ such that the equation $$x^2+4(\sin^{2}{x}\tan^{2}{x}+\cos^{2}{x}\cot^{2}{x}+k^2-x\sec{x}\csc{x})=0$$ has real roots?

I tried to find out the roots in terms of $k$.
But I couldn't.

How do we approach this problem without finding the roots actually?

Comment: What is that  csc x ?

Comment: Sorry for the ambiguity...It is $Cosecant(x)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^2- (4\sec{x}\csc{x})x +4(\sin^{2}{x}\tan^{2}{x}+\cos^{2}{x}\cot^{2}{x}+k^2)=0$$ Look for the discriminant, for real roots $D\ge 0 $ $$16\sec^2 x\csc^2 x-16(\sin^2 x\tan^2 x+\cos^2 x\cot^2 x+k^2)\ge 0$$ $$\frac{1}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}-\frac{\sin^4 x}{\cos^2 x}-\frac{\cos^4 x}{\sin^2 x}-k^2\ge 0$$ $$\frac{1-\sin^6 x-\cos^6 x}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\ge k^2$$ $$\frac{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x-\sin^6 x-\cos^6 x}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\ge k^2 $$ $$\frac{\sin^2 x(1-\sin^4 x)+\cos^2 x(1-\cos^4 x)}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\ge k^2$$ $$\frac{\sin^2 x(1-\sin^2 x)(1+\sin^2 x)+\cos^2 x(1-\cos^2 x)(1+\cos^2 x)}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\ge k^2$$ $$\frac{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x(1+\sin^2 x +1+\cos^2 x)}{\sin^2 x\cos^2 x}\ge k^2$$ $3\ge k^2$ $\implies -\sqrt3\le k\le \sqrt3\;$ So maximum value of $k$ is $\sqrt3$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
  C &\equiv \cos x \\
  S &\equiv \sin x \\
  0 &= x^2-(4\sec x \csc x)\, x+4(\sin^2 x \tan^2 x+\cos^2 x \cot^2 x+k^2) \\
  &= x^2-\frac{4x}{SC}+4\left( \frac{S^6+C^6}{S^2 C^2}+k^2 \right) \\
  \Delta &=
  \left( \frac{4}{SC} \right)^2-
  16\left( \frac{S^6+C^6}{S^2 C^2}+k^2 \right) \\
  &= 16\left[ \frac{1-(S^6+C^6)}{S^2C^2}-k^2 \right] \\
  &= 16
  \left[
    \frac{1-(\color{red}{S^2+C^2})(S^4-S^2C^2+C^4)}{S^2C^2}-k^2
  \right] \\
  &= 16\left[ \frac{1-(S^4-S^2C^2+C^4)}{S^2C^2}-k^2 \right] \\
  &= 16\left[ \frac{1+3S^2C^2-(\color{red}{S^2+C^2})^2}{S^2C^2}-k^2 \right] \\
  &= 16(3-k^2) \\
\end{align}

Therefore,

$$\fbox{$-\sqrt{3} \le k \le \sqrt{3} \,$}$$

Comment: ___How do you say that  $$\frac{1+3S^2C^2-(S^2+C^2)^2}{S^2C^2}=3?$$

Comment: $\color{red}{S^2+C^2 \equiv 1}$

Comment: Oh! You used the Pythagorean identity...

Comment: How did you get the second last equation with $3S^2C^2?$

Comment: Completing the square, $$S^4-S^2C^2+C^2 \equiv (S^4+2S^2C^2+C^4)-3S^2C^2 \equiv (S^2+C^2)^2-3S^2C^2$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73927/discussion-between-kshitij-m-bhat-and-ng-chung-tak).

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+4(\sin^{2}{x}\tan^{2}{x}+\cos^{2}{x}\cot^{2}{x}+k^2-x\sec{x}\csc{x})=0$$

$$x^2+4((1-\cos^{2}{x})\tan^{2}{x}+(1-\sin^{2}{x})\cot^{2}{x}+k^2-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}})=0$$

$$x^2+4(\tan^{2}{x}-\sin^{2}{x}+\cot^{2}{x}-\cos^{2}{x}+k^2-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}})=0$$

$$x^2+4(\tan^{2}{x}+\cot^{2}{x}-1+k^2-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}})=0$$

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+k^2-1+\tan^{2}{x}+\cot^{2}{x}-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}=0$$

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+k^2-1+\frac{\sin^{2}{x}}{\cos^{2}{x}}+\frac{\cos^{2}{x}}{\sin^{2}{x}}-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}=0$$

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+k^2-1+\frac{\sin^{4}{x}+\cos^{4}{x}}{\sin^{2}{x}\cos^{2}{x}}-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}=0$$

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+k^2-1+\frac{(\sin^{2}{x}+\cos^{2}{x})^2-2\sin^{2}{x}\cos^{2}{x}}{\sin^{2}{x}\cos^{2}{x}}-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}=0$$

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+k^2-1+\frac{1-2\sin^{2}{x}\cos^{2}{x}}{\sin^{2}{x}\cos^{2}{x}}-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}=0$$

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+k^2-3+\frac{1}{\sin^{2}{x}\cos^{2}{x}}-\frac{x}{\sin{x}\cos{x}}=0$$

$$\frac{x^2}{4}+k^2-3+\frac{4}{\sin^{2}{2x}}-\frac{2x}{\sin{2x}}=0$$

$$\left(\frac{2}{\sin{2x}}-\frac{x}{2}\right)^2=3-k^2$$

$$\frac{2}{\sin{2x}}-\frac{x}{2}=\pm\sqrt{3-k^2}$$

So we know $k \le \sqrt{3}$, otherwise the right hand side will not be real. When $k=\sqrt{3}$, the equation becomes $\sin{2x}=\frac{4}{x}$. This must have real solutions because $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{4}{x}=0$ and we know sin oscillates between -1 and 1.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest plugging your equation into the quadratic formula to get

$$ x = \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{(-16)(\sin^2 x \tan^2 x + \cos^2 x \cot^2 x +k^2 - x \sec x \csc x)}$$

From here we see we need

$$(-16)(\sin^2 x \tan^2 x + \cos^2 x \cot^2 x +k^2 - x \sec x \csc x) \gt 0$$

to have real roots.  Rearranging $\to$

$$ k^2 \lt  - \sin^2 x \tan^2 x - \cos^2 x \cot^2 x + x \sec x \csc x$$

Comment: I'm afraid $ k$ has a constant value.